# What to call the elements of a tensor product.

Tags: terminology

What does one call the first (or second) factor of an element of a tensor product? For example, if $V,W$ are vector spaces, and $v \in V$, $w \in W$, with $v \otimes w \in V \otimes W$, how would one refer to $v$? First tensor factor?

Comment: I think any denomination other than $v$ is confusing. The proof is that you are asking here, so it is hardly standard.

Comment: Tensorand? I've heard something like that before.

Comment: Call it the first projection of a representative of the tensor $v\otimes w=\otimes((v,w))$, so $(v,w)\in \otimes^{-1}(v\otimes w)\subset V\times W$.  

Comment: @ Andrea: But I've got a collection of about 116 $v \otimes w$'s, and I really don't want to refer to them individually. I need a way to say "Take all the first tensor factors and consider the ideal they generate".

Comment: The question is perfectly meaningful.  He's not suggesting v is uniquely determined by the tensor itself, but he just wants to know a label for those pieces of it.  You see, when I write the word pieces you know what I mean even though what I refer to has multiple answers. 

Comment: The single element $v\otimes w$ is often called a "pure tensor", so you could talk about the "first component(s)/factor(s) of the pure tensors". "First tensor factor" seems okay to me, since you'll have to define whatever locution you choose anyway. 

Comment: I would write "take the first member of each of the tensors $v\otimes w$", where "member of" could be replaced by "constituent of" or "factor of" if these sound better to your ear. (Maybe "factor of" is best, since $\otimes$ is the tensor *product*.)

Comment: I did not want to suggest that the question was not meaningful. Just that using a nonstandard name may cause more harm then good. But if it is clear from the context, everything from "piece" to "member" or "factor" will do.

Comment: Andrea, my comment above that the question is perfectly meaningful wasn't a response to your first comment, but rather to fpqc's initial comment, which has been removed. He had initially said that Aston's question is, strictly speaking, not well-defined or well-posed because tensor product spaces are usually constructed using cosets.  

Comment: In quantum mechanics, it is common to say something like "the first component" or otherwise "the first tensor factor" of the tensor product.  My preference is for "component" since it's less wordy.

Answer (score 8):

This issue is similar to what someone faces when dealing with a polynomial expression 
$$
c_n\alpha^n + c_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1} + \cdots + c_1\alpha + c_0
$$
where $\alpha$ actually satisfies an equation of degree smaller than $n$. Logically speaking such expressions can be written in multiple ways (consider a quartic polynomial expression in $\sqrt{3}$), but nobody has a problem speaking about the $i$th term in the expression.

Just do the same thing when you write down an elementary tensor $v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k$: call $v_i$ the $i$th component (or $i$th term, or perhaps even the $i$th factor). Now comes an issue of who your audience is (which you didn't indicate).  If your audience is experts, then it would be clear to your audience that whatever you're doing with $v_i$ is eventually leading to some well-defined result in terms of the tensor itself, so there's nothing more to say.

If your audience is students, to whom the tensor product is still somewhat new, then be sure to remind them that mathematically an elementary tensor does not have well-defined components, since an elementary tensor could be written as an elementary tensor in multiple ways. You might then mention the example of polynomial expressions as above which could be written in multiple ways, as an analogy.

Comment: Aston, now that you indicated in your comments what it is you actually wanted to do with the tensors, I can response more directly:  say you want to form the ideal generated by the first components of all the elementary tensors in your particular expression. 